# Facebook integration into the iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios4

I want to integrate facebook into my iphone app and can i find who are all online in the facebook programmatically using the facebook SDK

Please let me know your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook **iOS SDK** (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) cannot use chat out of the box from what I can tell.

Here are instructions for getting the SDK working in your iPhone app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Perhaps you could write a PHP (or language of your choice) script to interface with the web APIs that do allow you to get the list of users who are online. There is some PHP source code at the bottom of the following URL to do what you are trying to achieve.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/